# Checking if Field is Duplicate

Tags: sql, databricks-sql

I have a Students table like this:

| Name | Duplicate |
| --- | --- |
| John | no |
| Stacy | no |
| Kate | yes |
| John | yes |
| Stacy | yes |
| Kate | yes |

It is supposed to be the first record is not flagged as a duplicate but if I receive a repeat record that is flagged as a duplicate. I am trying to write a query that checks if there are any distinct names that are all flagged as duplicates. In this example table, all **Kate** records are flagged as duplicate so the query should only return Kate.

I have tried:

`select distinct Name from Students where duplicate='yes'`

but this returns John, Kate, and Stacy

Comment: First - according to what? Do you have some other column you can use to order the rows?

Comment: according to each name. Assuming this data comes in incremental load but there's no time information to compare. So essentially looking to group all the names together (all the records with John, Kate, and Stacy) and within each group check if there are any records that have duplicate='no'. If the group has no record with duplicate='no' (i.e. Kate), it returns the name.

Comment: Would a single Steve row, with 'yes', be returned?

Comment: No, in this case a single row with Kate. The records with 'John' and 'Stacy' have at least one record where duplicate='no'. Kate has no records where duplicate='no' so I would want Kate returned.

Comment: The accepted answer would return a single Steve yes row.

Answer (score 2):

Do a `GROUP BY`, use `HAVING` to return names with only 'yes' rows.

```
select name
from students
group by name
having min(duplicate) = 'yes'

   and count(*) > 1   -- add this if student name must occur more than once
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing it direct, as far as I can see, you want

1. All distinct `Name` such that
2. They are from `Duplicate = 'yes'` records
3. All such records must be `Duplicate = 'yes'` records; i.e. records `Duplicate = 'yes'` should not exist

```
select distinct s.Name 
  from s.Students
 where s.Duplicate = 'yes'
   and not exists ( 
         select 1
           from Students x
          where x.Duplicate = 'no'
            and x.Name = s.Name
       )
```